# Increase spacing/padding between legend labels in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am using Plots.jl with the GR backend to produce some plots in JuliaLang. I have noticed that when using LaTeXStrings.jl to produce Latex strings in the legend labels that the labels are close together. To illustrate what I'm referring to, I've edited the [JuliaPlots linestyle example](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/gr/) to use Latex strings in the legend labels. The code is as follows:

```
using Plots; gr()
using LaTeXStrings

styles = filter((s->begin
            s in Plots.supported_styles()
        end), [:solid, :dash, :dot, :dashdot, :dashdotdot])

styles = reshape(styles, 1, length(styles))
n = length(styles)
y = cumsum(randn(20, n), dims = 1)

plot(y, line = (5, styles), label = [L"s^{ol}_{id}" L"d^{as}_h" L"d^{o}_{t}" L"d^{ash}_{dot}" L"dash^{dot}_{dot}"], legendtitle = "linestyle")
```

The above code produces the following plot:

[image: Plots.jl with LaTeXStrings in the legend]

As you can see, the subscripts of one label are very close to the superscripts of the label directly beneath. Similarly for the legend title.

I would like to increase the spacing/padding between each label so there is a gap between the super- and sub-scripts of each label, but have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More advanced legend formatting seems to be available only for `pyplot()` backend.
However, when working with `gr()` I sometimes use this very ugly trick:

```
plot(y, line = (5, styles), label = [L"^{s^{ol}_{id}}" L"^{d^{as}_h}" L"^{d^{o}_{t}}" L"^{d^{ash}_{dot}}" L"^{dash^{dot}_{dot}}"],legendtitle = "linestyle",legendfontsize=14.0)
```

[image]